# Distinct Numbers in Windows

Tags: c++, data-structures, maps

This is my code but it's not giving correct output.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> Solution::dNums(vector<int> &A, int B) {
    vector<int> v;

    if(B>A.size()) {
        return v;
    }
    int n=A.size();

    for(int i=0;i<min(i+B,n);i++) {
        int smallest=INT_MAX,largest=INT_MIN;
        unordered_map<int,int> mp;

        for(int j=i;j<(i+B);j++) {
            mp[A[j]]++;
            smallest = min(smallest,A[j]);
            largest = max(largest,A[j]);
        }
        int c=0;

        for(int j=smallest;j<=largest;j++) {
            if(mp[j]>0) {
                c++;
            }
        }
        v.push_back(c);
    }
    return v;
}
```

**For the test case:**

A : [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3 ]

B : 3

Code is giving: 2 3 3 2 3 2

Actual output is: 2 3 3 2

**Explanation:** You are given an array of N integers, A1, A2 ,..., AN and an integer B. Return the of count of distinct numbers in all windows of size B.

Formally, return an array of size N-B+1 where i'th element in this array contains number of distinct elements in sequence Ai, Ai+1 ,..., Ai+B-1.

NOTE: if B > N, return an empty array.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't forget how to [edit] your question to improve them (like for example stating what debugging efforts you have made).

Comment: Please describe what the function is supposed to accomplish. (An unexplained example doesn't count.)